# Can a single thread consume more than one queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a Java thread that calls `basicConsume(String queueName,...)` to fetch messages from a RabbitMQ server.

Can a *single* thread block on more than one queue at once, e.g. `consume(List<String> queues,...)` where it returns the first available item from any of those queues?

I have looked at [the API](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.0.4/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.0.4/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html) but not found any way to do this.

Comment: I think you are going to need more than 1 thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait on multiple queues, you can simply create a `Consumer` (it can be a `QueueingConsumer` or a custom one) and call multiple times `basicConsume()` on your queues with this same consumer instance as an argument.

That way, the `handleDelivery()` callback will be called when (or, in the case of a `QueueingConsumer`, `consumer.nextDelivery()` will block until) the first item from the queues is available.